# Mount usb storage before using camera

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm using Ice Cream Sandwich Tablet (7"). When I try to use my camera, this statement pops out "mount usb storage before using camera"....What do I have to do?...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Camera in Android is  created for storing photos on external storage. On phones this can be microSD or internal big storage. As I think, your tablet don't have slot for SD card so you need to insert USB flash drive, on which Camera will store photos (or insert SD card, if your tablet has this slot).